# Navigation panel links in the form of parallelograms - straight text needed

Tags: html, css

I am working on navigation panels. I used skewX on the links but it skews the text also. Is it possible to make the text straight, as in vertical. 
I tried doing `<a href.....><p>Assassin's Creed</p></a>` then skewing the text but it spoils the display,

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
li {
 float: left;
}
li a {
 margin: 15px;
 background-color: red;
 display:block;
 border: 2px solid white;
 padding: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: skewX(30deg);
 transition: box-shadow 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
}
li a:hover {
 box-shadow: 10px 0px 1px cyan, -10px 0px 1px cyan ;
    background-color: black;
}
div a img:hover {
 opacity: 1.0;
 width: 290px;
 margin: 5px 0 0 0;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styleweb.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="som.html"><b>Shadow of Mordor</b></a></li>
   <li><a href="tr.html"><b>Tomb Raider</b></a></li>
   <li><a href="ac.html"><b>Assassin's Creed</b></a></li>
   <li><a href="bf4.html"><b>Battlefield 4</b></a></li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Skew the text back the other way with:

```
li a b {
    transform: skewX(-30deg);
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

**Note:** `tranform` does not work *automatically* on inline elements such as `span` tags or `b` tags...so we have to set the `display:property` to something more appropriate..in this case `inline-block`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
}
li a b {
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 1px cyan, -10px 0px 1px cyan;
  background-color: black;
}
div a img:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  width: 290px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styleweb.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="som.html"><b>Shadow of Mordor</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="tr.html"><b>Tomb Raider</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="ac.html"><b>Assassin's Creed</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="bf4.html"><b>Battlefield 4</b></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**One final note**..the `b` tag is probably inappropriate here...you should be using a styled `span` tag instead.

> Historically, the  element was meant to make text boldface. Styling information has been deprecated since HTML4, so the meaning of the  element has been changed.
>
> If there is no semantic purpose on using the  element, using css property font-weight with bold value would be a better choice for making text bold.